# New virtual env bringing a large number of installed packages with it

Tags: python

I'm a new python developer. I'm working on my first project. When creating my new virtual environment on my system, I did the following command:

```
python -m venv flask-env
```

I'm able to activate the environment. And when I do, if I do a "pip list" command it lists many installed packages, specifically a bunch associated with anaconda (I've played around with anaconda).

When I push my hello world version of my new app to Heroku, however, I'm getting failed deployment with some mentions of anaconda packages.

How do I start this with a clean environment? (The anaconda packages aren't relevant for this project). I've researched for hours on best practices here, but I can't seem to find any clear instructions on this.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using your systems python rather than Anaconda's to create the venv?

Comment: @Evert I activated the virtual env. The command line added the (flask-env) in the prompt indicating I was inside the virtual env.

Comment: @cricket_007 How do I do that? I just used the python -m venv flask-env command as instructed in the tutorial I was using.

Comment: Replace `python` with `/usr/bin/python`